# PHP-EWS - Subscription / PushNotification - complete example

Tags: php, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, php-ews

after two frustrating days I give up.
I have one virtual maschine "admx" with Win2012R2 + Exchange 2013 (Trailversion) and
one virtual maschine "webserver" with a IIS-Webserver+PHP.

Make a new Subscription - sub.php:

```
<?PHP
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    // Start from the base path and determine the location from the class name,
    $base_path = 'php-ews';
    $include_file = $base_path . '/' . str_replace('_', '/', $class_name) . '.php';
    //$include_file = str_replace('_', '/', $class_name) . '.php';

    return (file_exists($include_file) ? require_once $include_file : false);
}

$server = "admx";
$host = $server;
$username = "administrator@testdom.local";
$password = "secret123";
$version = "Exchange2013";

$url = "http://webserver/testexchange/log.php";
$keepAliveFrequency = 1;

$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($server, $username, $password, $version);
$subscribe_request = new EWSType_SubscribeType();
$pushSubscription = new EWSType_PushSubscriptionRequestType();
$pushSubscription->StatusFrequency = $keepAliveFrequency;
$pushSubscription->URL = $url;
$folderIDs = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
$eventTypes = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfNotificationEventTypesType();
$folderIDs->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$folderIDs->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::INBOX;
$eventTypes->EventType = "NewMailEvent";
$pushSubscription->FolderIds = $folderIDs;
$pushSubscription->EventTypes = $eventTypes;
$subscribe_request->PushSubscriptionRequest = $pushSubscription;
$response = $ews->Subscribe($subscribe_request);

var_dump($response);
?>
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#10 (1) { ["ResponseMessages"]=> object(stdClass)#11 (1) { ["SubscribeResponseMessage"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (4) { ["ResponseCode"]=> string(7) "NoError" ["ResponseClass"]=> string(7) "Success" ["SubscriptionId"]=> string(64) "EgBhZG14LnRlc3Rkb20ubG9jYWwQAAAA3keYE/U5Mkacz2FAg6DfHKdXyqelf9II" ["Watermark"]=> string(40) "AQAAAF57K7d1ihJLl9odwZ02gVahGgAAAAAAAAA=" } } }
```

So, the subscription is successfully registered.
Here is the listener - log.php

```
<?PHP
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages\">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:SendNotificationResult>
            <ns1:SubscriptionStatus>OK</ns1:SubscriptionStatus>
        </ns1:SendNotificationResult>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

file_put_contents("C:\\exlog\\only_ok_".time().".txt", print_r($_REQUEST,1));
?>
```

Now I get every minute (because $keepAliveFrequency = 1;) a new respone / StatusCheck from the Exchange-Server. When I send a eMail to administrator@testdom.local I get a new notification immediately too (because "NewMailEvent" in Inbox).
I acknowledge it with OK as XML, to keep-alive the subscription...
So far so good.

But in the logfile (only_ok_1435488594.txt) is only...

```
Array()
```

Update log.php to get notification-information:

```
<?PHP
 class ewsService {
    public function SendNotification( $arg ) {
        file_put_contents("C:\\exlog\\logfile2_".time().".txt", print_r($arg,1));
        $result = new EWSType_SendNotificationResultType();
        $result->SubscriptionStatus = 'OK';
        //$result->SubscriptionStatus = 'Unsubscribe';
        return $result;
    }
}


$server = new SoapServer( 'php-ews/wsdl/NotificationService.wsdl', array(    'uri' => 'http://webserver/testexchange/log.php'));
$server->setObject( $service = new ewsService() );
$server->handle();
?>
```

And now the logfile as more informations as "array()":

```
stdClass Object
(
    [ResponseMessages] => stdClass Object
        (
            [SendNotificationResponseMessage] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ResponseCode] => NoError
                    [ResponseClass] => Success
                    [Notification] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [SubscriptionId] => EgBhZG14LnRlc3Rkb20ubG9jYWwQAAAAvfY+2ehqCEOXroWYNAsn+mD+ZBQYf9II
                            [PreviousWatermark] => AQAAAF57K7d1ihJLl9odwZ02gVZNGAAAAAAAAAA=
                            [MoreEvents] => 
                            [StatusEvent] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Watermark] => AQAAAF57K7d1ihJLl9odwZ02gVZNGAAAAAAAAAA=
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Problem: 
The Subscriptions gets after 3 more notifications lost. From the MSDN-documentation I know, the Exchangeserver retry 3-times the statusmessage to get a "OK" from the listener.

I has download the NotificationService.wsdl from GoogleSearch.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2007 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" schemaLocation="messages.xsd"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="SendNotificationSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:SendNotification" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="SendNotificationSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="SendNotificationResult" element="tns:SendNotificationResult" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="NotificationServicePortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="SendNotification">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:SendNotificationSoapIn" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:SendNotificationSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>


    <wsdl:binding name="NotificationServiceBinding" type="tns:NotificationServicePortType">
        <wsdl:documentation>
            <wsi:Claim conformsTo="http://ws-i.org/profiles/basic/1.0" xmlns:wsi="http://ws-i.org/schemas/conformanceClaim/" />
        </wsdl:documentation>
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />

        <wsdl:operation name="SendNotification">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/SendNotification" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>


    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:binding name="NotificationServiceBinding12" type="tns:NotificationServicePortType">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />

        <wsdl:operation name="SendNotification">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/SendNotification" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>

        <wsdl:service name="NotificationServices">
    <wsdl:port name="NotificationServicePort" binding="tns:NotificationServiceBinding">
        <soap:address location="" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>


</wsdl:definitions>
```

I have also add this, because without it I get a "bind error"

```
<wsdl:service name="NotificationServices">
    <wsdl:port name="NotificationServicePort" binding="tns:NotificationServiceBinding">
        <soap:address location="" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I'm no Pro in SOAP... Whats going wrong here?
Thank you
Olli

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working and complete example:
https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/issues/280